# what does ''too blessed to be stressed'' meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does "too blessed to be stressed" meaning?

Is it he/she trying to say too blessed, there is nothing to be stressed?

Comment: So much at one with the spirit of the universe (or with the Christian God) that trivial worries will not upset you. The source or foundation  of the "blessedness" will vary according to the religion, if any, which the speaker practices.

Comment: The context in which you're hearing/reading this would be helpful to provide a better answer.

Comment: A related idiom is [to count one's blessings](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+blessings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Too blessed to be stressed" means that you are well-off enough in life that you shouldn't be worrying about trivial matters. It is a way of looking at your life from a macro perspective and remembering to be thankful for what you have.

For example, if you drop your smartphone on the ground, and the screen breaks, that'd be a bummer, but it's not worth wasting your mental and emotional energy actually stressing about it. If your biggest worry in life is that your smartphone screen broke – and not, say, whether you'll have anywhere to sleep tonight or where your next meal is going to come from – then you're "too blessed to be stressed."

While "blessed" typically has a religious connotation, it doesn't necessarily carry any such connotation in the phrase "too blessed to be stressed." You may just as well hear the phrase from an atheist as a deeply religious person. The phrase is just a way to generally relate a particular attitude toward life that some people have where they try not to get upset over the little things.

Answer (score 0):

BLESSED TO BE STRESSED means that the person has faith in God, and considers themselves blessed by God, and so doesn't let life's stresses get to them too much.

Answer (score -1):

> **Too blessed to be stressed.**

Well, besides the fact that it rhymes so well, from what I can comprehend from this is that, when a person is **blessed**, he is bestowed upon a lot of good wishes. The person wishes that the subject has no obstacles in achieving anything. The speaker hopes that whatever the subject does, it turns out to be exactly what the he wanted.

Now, a person becomes really stressful when he doesn't see expected results. He gets annoyed when obstacles prevent/ delay him from attaining what he wants.

Say, for example, Adam is throwing a party. A few hours prior to the arrival of his guests, he finds out that the caterers have screwed up the dishes. He also gets to know that a blizzard is on its way, and people might be snowed in. Nothing is working out. His wife tells him that this is karma doing its part because Adam was mean to his parents. She tells him that if he had their blessing, he wouldn't have so much problems with his life.

Jake, on the other hand, was a perfect family man. He had a joint family of many elders and he was blessed by all of them. He decides to throw a birthday party for his uncle. He learns that everybody his uncle wanted to meet is available for the party, even though they were called on such short notice. He finds a caterer and the caterer tells him that he's their 1000th customer and thus, the service is on the house. Everything's happening as planned, and somethings, even better. One could say that his blessings accounted for all this, and that's why his is so relaxed and stress-free.

As for your context, we cannot assume that blessing is the sole solution to a stress-free life, but if you are blessed, you might not encounter as many problems as say, a guy, who isn't that '*blessed*'.

**Note**: *This is strictly an example. I cannot be held accountable if bad things happen to anybody, even if they are blessed.*

Comment: With a few exceptions, native Anglo speakers do not seek the "blessing" of their elders in this way. In AmE and BrE, when we have someone's blessing, we have their permission, not their benediction.